# Why is the left alignment leaving space in table?

Tags: tables

I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|L{0.2\textwidth}|L{0.2\textwidth}L{0.2\textwidth}L{0.2\textwidth}|}\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\large Physical Properties} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\large Solid} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\large Liquid} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\large Gas} \\ \hline
Shape & Definite & Indefinite & Indefinite \\ \hline
Volume & Definite & Definite & Indefinite \\ \hline
Force of Attraction & Very Strong & Less than solid & Least \\ \hline
Fluidity & Doesn't flow & Can flow & Can blow \\ \hline
Compressibility & Can't be compressed & Can't be compressed & Highly compressed \\ \hline
Diffusion & Very Slow & Fast & Fastest \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

which produces (the unwanted spaces are marked in yellow):
[image]

The items in the leftmost column *are* aligned to the left (as wanted) but leave some space before beginning.

How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnKormylo Could you please add an answer? I tried but it shows an error saying `Misplaced \omit` (due to the `\multicolumn` maybe?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prescribed width of the first column is smaller than width of the `\multicolumn` cell in it. Simpler remedy is to use natural width for this column:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{c|}m}{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{longtable}{|l | *{3}{L{0.2\textwidth}|} }
    \hline
\large Physical Properties 
    &   \mcc{\large Solid} 
        & \mcc{\large Liquid} 
            & \mcc{\large Gas}                              \\ \hline
Shape       & Definite      & Indefinite    & Indefinite    \\ \hline
Volume      & Definite      & Definite      & Indefinite    \\ \hline
Force of Attraction 
            & Very Strong   & Less than solid 
                                            & Least         \\ \hline
Fluidity    & Doesn't flow  & Can flow      & Can blow      \\ \hline
Compressibility 
            & Can't be compressed 
                            & Can't be compressed 
                                            & Highly compressed \\ \hline
Diffusion   & Very Slow     & Fast          & Fastest           \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I wonder, if you really need `longtable` for this table? If it is shorter than one page, is sensible (at least to my opinion) to use `tabularx` table. In this case you not need to take a care that table is not wider to `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{c|}m}{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l | *{3}{L|} }
    \hline
\large Physical Properties 
    &   \mcc{\large Solid} 
        & \mcc{\large Liquid} 
            & \mcc{\large Gas}                              \\ \hline
Shape       & Definite      & Indefinite    & Indefinite    \\ \hline
Volume      & Definite      & Definite      & Indefinite    \\ \hline
Force of Attraction 
            & Very Strong   & Less than solid 
                                            & Least         \\ \hline
Fluidity    & Doesn't flow  & Can flow      & Can blow      \\ \hline
Compressibility 
            & Can't be compressed 
                            & Can't be compressed 
                                            & Highly compressed \\ \hline
Diffusion   & Very Slow     & Fast          & Fastest           \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Result is almost the same as before.

**Addendum:**
If table is longer than one page, you may consider to use `xltabular` table. Beside this, considering your question in comment below, use `makecell` and `booktabs` packages, without vertical rules:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
\normalsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ L{1.15} *{3}{L{0.95}} }
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Physical\\ Properties} 
    &   \thead[l]{Solid} 
        & \thead[l]{Liquid} 
            & \thead[l]{Gas}                              \\ 
    \midrule
Shape       & Definite      & Indefinite    & Indefinite    \\ 
Volume      & Definite      & Definite      & Indefinite    \\ 
    \addlinespace
Force of Attraction 
            & Very Strong   & Less than solid 
                                            & Least         \\ 
Fluidity    & Doesn't flow  & Can flow      & Can blow      \\ 
    \addlinespace
Compressibility 
            & Can't be compressed 
                            & Can't be compressed 
                                            & Highly compressed \\ 
Diffusion   & Very Slow     & Fast          & Fastest           \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, this table is a part of a bigger project, so I use `longtable`s to be carefree of pagebreaks.

Comment: I just wanted to ask, how do I manage if there is an item in left most column that exceeds the width of `Physical Properties`, taking into account I don't want the text area to increase further?

Comment: @BookOfFlames, that is mater of personal preference. I would design your table quite differently: without vertical lines, with rules defined in the `booktabs` package and for column headers use `makecell` package enabling two line text in them and also not increase font size in the columns headers.

Answer (score 2):

You must increase width of first column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable, array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|L{0.3\textwidth}|L{0.2\textwidth}L{0.2\textwidth}L{0.2\textwidth}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\large Physical Properties} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\large Solid} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\large Liquid} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\large Gas} \\ \hline
Shape & Definite & Indefinite & Indefinite \\ \hline
Volume & Definite & Definite & Indefinite \\ \hline
Force of Attraction & Very Strong & Less than solid & Least \\ \hline
Fluidity & Doesn't flow & Can flow & Can blow \\ \hline
Compressibility & Can't be compressed & Can't be compressed & Highly compressed \\ \hline
Diffusion & Very Slow & Fast & Fastest \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```